# Good design pattern for a tool to combine many log files

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a lot of log files in different formats. Each log files has different kinds of data from which I can make out the the time and source of the log message along with other details.

I need to combine all the log messages into one big log file with my own format and which should be sorted by time of the log messages.

I also plan to implement a GUI as well as a command line interface for the tool.

Is strategy pattern a good design strategy for this? Since I want to develop a CUI as well as a GUI, would the strategy pattern be a good fit?

Comment: I realize your question is about the correct design, and you've already decided to create a tool.  But CLI tool [_Super Speedy Syslog Searcher_](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher) can sort logs. Maybe that will be satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

One could split the problem into multiple smaller ones.

- Log file reading
- Log file parsing
- Combining the log files
- Displaying the combined log

**Log file reading**
The log files can come from multiple sources. It can be a local file or somewhere on the network. Probably the readers are stateful objects that remember the file size and the position they are currently at. One example of a log file location could be `http://myserver.mycompany.com/logs/job.log` One could create an interface for the readers and then multiple implementations. The Factory pattern could be utilized to create the correct implementation given a log file location.

**Log file parsing**
Once the raw data is available in some memory chunk it should be parsed. Here one could utilize the Composite pattern: log has multiple log lines which has multiple log columns.

**Combining the log files**
When one has multiple parsed logs available they need to be combined into one. Presuming that each log line has a log column with timestamp available it is quite straightforward to sort the lines by the time column.

**Displaying the combined log**
Assuming at this stage one has acquired a combined log with lines and columns it is easy utilize this data model in the chosed display technology, be it console or GUI.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only variable part of your problem is format of input files. This means that you may use factory to get correct parser.

1. Read file
2. Determine log format based on something inside file. Use factory to return correct parser.

---

Factory in its simplest form will look similar to this

```
if(someIdicatorFromFile.equals("oneTypeOfFormat"){
    return new ParserForFormatOne();
}
else if(someIdicatorFromFile.equals("otherTypeOfFormat"){
    return new ParserForOtherFormat();
}
```

---

3. After this step you won't need any patterns. It's just call to `parser.parse()`. Parser should return some common format.
4. Display results